# Entity Framework Core Automapper latest viewed items for a specific user

Tags: entity-framework-core, automapper, fluent

Using Entity Framework Core, I would like to get a list of the 10 most recently viewed jobs by a user.

I am working on a CRM which contains `User`, `Job` and `UserJobView` classes.

```
public class User
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Job
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
}

public class UserJobView
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid JobId { get; set; }
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastViewedAt { get; set; }

    public Job Job { get; set; }
}
```

I also have a `JobDto` which I project to using AutoMapper

```
public class JobDto : IMapFrom<Job>
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastViewedAt { get; set; }
}
```

Each time a `User` views a `Job` I either update or create a `UserJobView` object setting the `LastViewedAt` property to be `DateTime.Now`

I can get the latest viewed items with the following fluent query

```
return await _context.UserJobViews 
    .Where(x => x.UserId == thisUserId)
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.LastViewed)
    .Take(10)
    .Select(x => x.Job)
    .ProjectTo<JobDto>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider)
    .ToListAsync();
```

However this obviously doesn't populate the `LastViewedAt` property for the `JobDto`. How might I go about doing this?

Comment: `CreateMap<UserJobView, JobDto>().IncludeMembers(s => s.Job)`.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu If you make that an official answer I'll accept it because that's exactly what I was after thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a small addition to your configuration, you can make it happen:

```
CreateMap<UserJobView, JobDto>().IncludeMembers(s => s.Job);
```